# Specify device width for session requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests

How to specify the device width while I do a session.post ?
Example of code :

```
import requests
global session

session = requests.Session()
payload = {
    "login_email" : "helloyes",
}
url = "https://www.twitter.com/"

result = session.post(url, data=payload, headers=dict(Referer=url))
plain_text = result.content
content = plain_text.decode()
```

This code renders a mobile device view of the website. I need the desktop view, how to do please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `User-Agent` corresponding to a mobile browser in the headers of your request:

```
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
headers_dict = {
    "Referer": url,
    "User-Agent": user_agent
}
result = session.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers_dict)
```

You can find a list of mobile user agents on [useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?typ=Mobile%20Browser). Then, you can pick a user agent corresponding to some device that has your specific width.